# grab text from one textField, change it and pass to another textField

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have 2 textfields and a button.
in first I enter text.
in second I get the changed text.

```
#import "tcViewController.h"

@interface tcViewController ()

@end

@implementation tcViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.textField.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}

- (IBAction)changeText:(id)sender {
_textField2.text = _textField.text;
}

@end
```

how can I change text for example from "text" to "TEXT" when pressing a button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to make:

```
[_textField2 setText:[_textField.text uppercaseString]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)changeText:(id)sender {
    _textField2.text = [_textField.text uppercaseString];

}
```